# jsonb_each to access elements inside objects

Tags: json, postgresql, jsonb

I have a JSON column (called "roi") which contains users' Instagram performance. This is the roi column:

```
{
"data": {
    "campaignName": "Master Cosy",
    "currency": "GBP",
    "reportData": {
        "AAAAAAAAAA": {
            "id": "0f20d833-d0f-bdb7-19",
            "name": "cornish_gregorys",
            "thumbnail": "https://sstagram.com/v/t51.2885-19/s320x320/87244862_1017848048596",
            "Name": "cornisorys",
            "instagramCount": 2319,
            "instagramEngagementFactor": 0,
            "instagramAuthorised": true,
            "hasPosts": true,
            "budget": 0,
            "derivedFee": 0,
            "inventoryItems": [],
            "trackedAssetsStats": {
                "totalAssets": 9,
                "facebook": {
                    "count": 0
                },
                "instagram": {
                    "total": 9,
                    "stories": 9,
                    "carousels": 0,
                    "videos": 0,
                    "images": 0,
                    "igtvs": 0
                },
        "BBBBBBBBBBBBB": {
            "id": "d3d30db4-0b453dfc3ae2a09",
            "name": "itssdha",
            "thumbnail": "https://in9809609728_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fhel5-1.fna.fbcdn.net&_nc_ohc=Se3ySAoqnFwAX4f6&oeF1623",
            "Name": "itsshdha",
            "instagramCount": 26700,
            "instagramEngagementFactor": 0,
            "instagramAuthorised": true,
            "hasPosts": true,
            "budget": 0,
            "derivedFee": 0,
            "inventoryItems": [],
            "trackedAssetsStats": {
                "totalAssets": 5,
                "facebook": {
                    "count": 0
                },
            "instagram": {
                "total": 9,
                "stories": 9,
                "carousels": 0,
                "videos": 0,
                "images": 0,
                "igtvs": 0}, etc.....
```

After "reportData" I have the specific names of the users (in this case AAAAAAAA and BBBBBBBBB) and within them the performance of their Instagram accounts. How can I access all the metrics within the object username without having to type the specific username (AAAAAAAA and BBBBBBBBB)

My query is this:

```
roi -> 'date' -> 'reportData' -> 'AAAAAAA' -> 'instagramCount' -> etc ....
```

But I need something to 'jump' this part `-> 'AAAAAAA' ->` and go straight to the metrics, in this case `'instagramCount'`, etc...

From what I have read I may need to use **jsonb_each**, does anyone know how to use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[demos:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=c2e0cbb09b739c745ca20963b547dcd5)

You have several ways.

1. Use `jsonb_each()` to expand all users' data: You can create a record per user and than ask for the `count` afterwards

   ```
   SELECT
       users.value -> 'instagramCount'
   FROM
       mytable,
       jsonb_each(mydata -> 'data' -> 'reportData') as users
   ```
2. **Since Postgres 12** you can use JSONpath for that, to achieve the same:

   ```
   SELECT 
       jsonb_path_query(mydata, '$.**.instagramCount') 
   FROM mytable
   ```

Comment: thanks S-Man, what can I do if I want to deepen the destructuring of the JSON?
for example how should I modify the query if I want to access the element inside "trackedAssetsStats" or  "instagram"

Comment: Approach 1: Just add `->` operators to the users.value SELECT. Approach 2: Switch `instagramCount` with whatever you want.

Comment: last thing. what if I want to extract a string from reportData? I tried with: 
users.text -> 'stringt' but it doesn't work.
with users.value -> 'stringt' I get a JSON column instead of a tex one

Comment: Please have a look into the spec.: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html You can use the `->>` operator for that.

Comment: Hey S-Man, do you know any alternative to "jsonb_each(mydata -> 'data' -> 'reportData') " to use in Redshift?

Comment: No, I fear you want have any chances, because Redshift is based on a very old Postgres version, which didn't support json at this level. I guess you would end with manual string parsing or do this in your backing. Sorry. You should think about parsing your JSON before insert it into the database when you're using Redshift.